# pandas index.asof with multiindex

Tags: python, pandas

I have data with a time series for each entity:

```
id  event_date  value
1   2013-12-21  3.82
1   2013-12-22  2.47
1   2013-12-25  2.13
1   2014-01-03  3.92
1   2014-01-04  2.48
2   2014-10-16  3.96
2   2014-10-17  3.61
2   2014-10-29  2.59
2   2014-11-05  3.64
2   2014-11-15  2.85
```

I've put it in a dataframe with a multiindex:

```
               value
id event_date
1  2013-12-21   3.82
   2013-12-22   2.47
   2013-12-25   2.13
   2014-01-03   3.92
   2014-01-04   2.48
2  2014-10-16   3.96
   2014-10-17   3.61
   2014-10-29   2.59
   2014-11-05   3.64
   2014-11-15   2.85
```

I'm trying to find the latest date before an arbitrary cut off (say before 2014-10-31 or 2014-09-30) in the series for each id. index.asof or Series.asof seems to be what I want but I can't figure out how to use it with multiple indices. For a date of '2014-10-30' I want this output:

```
id  event_date
1   2014-01-04 00:00:00
2   2014-10-29 00:00:00
```

I can get there by looping over the first level index but it seems like there should be a better more pandonic way (the full data set is pretty large) and I'm just missing it.

```
In [10]: for idx in df.index.levels[0]:
   ....:     print idx, df.loc[idx].index.asof('2014-10-30')
   ....:
1 2014-01-04 00:00:00
2 2014-10-29 00:00:00
```

There is no reason the data has to be in this multiindex structure, just seems to make sense given I have a timeseries for each id. The times are sorted and there are no duplicates.

versions:
pandas: 0.15.0
numpy: 1.9.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that @gjreda's answer was only missing your cutoff filter, so assuming `event_date` and `id` are **not** in the index:

```
cutoff = '2014-10-30'
df[df['event_date'] <= cutoff].groupby(['id'])['event_date'].last()
```

This gives the same output as before but the cutoff is arbitrary:

```
id
1    2014-01-04
2    2014-10-29
Name: event_date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

And if you still want to use those columns in the index you could do:

```
df[df.index.levels[1] <= cutoff].groupby(level=['id']).apply(lambda x: x.index.get_level_values(1).max())
```

By the way it seems `.asof` when applied to the `groupby` dataframe evaluates the whole index and not the index of the group, so your version with `asof` does not work as expected:

```
df[df.index.levels[1] <= cutoff].groupby(level=[0]).apply(lambda x: x.index.levels[1].asof(cutoff))
```

Returns:

```
id
1    2014-10-29
2    2014-10-29
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Which looks like it used the last true value for all groups.

Answer (score 0):

If there's no reason for it to be in a MultiIndex, you can do something like this:

```
In [10]: df.reset_index(inplace=True)
In [11]: df.groupby('id')['event_date'].max()
Out[11]: 
id
1     2014-01-04
2     2014-11-15
Name: event_date, dtype: object
```

```

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't totally clear in my question. I'm trying to find the latest date before some arbitrary cut off. So the nearest date at Oct month end for example. edited the question to clarify.

Comment: Whoops, missed that, but @Primer's got you.